# Static files with Flask in production

Tags: static, flask, production-environment

Usually, the problem is how to serve static files in development environment, while in my case it is the opposite. So I've deployed a Flask application using Apache and mod_wsgi, configured Apache to serve my static files at /static url. And now I'm not sure, whether those files are being served by Apache or by Flask, since flask is also using by default the same path for static.

In templates I use url_for("static", filename="style.css"). And it works fine. But this is the problem, because I don't know what is serving my static files. Of course, I can be sure that Apache is serving, if I change every template to have hardcoded path and something different than default Flask, but this doesn't sound like the right solution.

So to sum up my question: how to use url_for(static) in Flask (templates) and be sure, that Flask is not serving them for me?

Thanks,
Rapolas K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Set another static folder (you will need also create empty folder on file system):

   ```
   app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='static', static_folder='static_test')
   ```

   So if you get 404 then files serving by flask else apache.
2. Add test folder and map apache as for static folder.

   So if you get content from test folder then files serving by apache else flask.
3. Break any `static` endpoint requests:

   ```
   @app.before_request
   def break_static():
       if request.endpoint == 'static':
           abort(404)
       return None
   ```

   or

   ```
   class YourApp(Flask):
       def send_static_file(self, filename):
           abort(404)
   ```

   So if you get 404 then files serving by flaks else apache.

But you enough once test this case if you realy not sure. If apache configuration will not changing then static serving behaviour will not changing too.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question. After the 1., I got that files were served by Flask, and not by Apache. So it looks like a workaround, to add some fake static_folder option to Flask app, otherwise it is not clear what serves those static files... But leaves a question is there a performance penalty, that Flask is always trying to serve static files.

Comment: Probably you have wrong apache config because with right settings apache must handle this files from setted directory.

Comment: I changed apache conf to serve a different directory on purpose, to see that Flask is also serving those files. And that was my concern, if both Flask and Apache are serving from the same directory, I can't know which takes precedence. After setting Flask to serve empty directory, I'm sure now that Apache is taking care of static files.

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure as long as you have this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The app.run() call actually starts the local development server. In production, you will/should never have to call this and hence nothing can be served by the dev. server since it is never started.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If I change Apache to serve files on a different path, those files are still being accessible via old Flask static path, together with a new apache path. But url_for generates Flask path, not the one served by Apache.